# javafx spinner hide arrows

Tags: user-interface, javafx, spinner

How can I hide arrows of a spinner on JAJAFX?

I tried to set the style of the spinner to :

```
.increment-arrow-button .increment-arrow { -fx-padding: 0;}

.decrement-arrow-button .decrement-arrow { -fx-padding: 0;}
```

and

```
.spinner .increment-arrow-button .increment-arrow { -fx-padding: 0;} 
.spinner .decrement-arrow-button .decrement-arrow { -fx-padding: 0;}
```

using `spinner.setStyle("...");` but without results

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cant test it right now but try to override the `.spinner .increment-arrow-button .increment-arrow { -fx-shape: "";}` and the same for the decrement

Comment: @JKostikiadis That is correct.

Comment: You should also set padding to `0` so that there won't be awkward gaps.

Comment: @Jai this is what I did (see my post)

Comment: @JKostikiadis I'll try

Comment: @Jai I didn't read your answer well, you said that I should ALSO (in addition to shape) set padding, I'll try, thank you

Comment: @JKostikiadis ,Jai it doesn't work, I've tried all combinations without results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem without using Style, what worked for me is this :

```
spinner.getStyleClass().clear();
```